# Modify the number of confirmations for an utxo to be ```safe == true``` in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, confirmations

I noticed that when I call `listunspent` on Bitcoin Core, UTXO with 0 confirmation are labeled `unsafe`, and thus prevented from being spent with `sendtoaddress` or `fundrawtransaction`. As soon as there's one confirmation the tx is `safe` and I can spend it.

Being able to modify the target for a tx to be considered `safe`, for example set it to 3 or 6 confirmations instead of just 1, would make my life easier, but I can't find an option for it. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: You could set `minconf=3` or `minconf=6` for that matter; you can also parse depending on the `confirmations` field instead of the `safe` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.19.0/rpc/wallet/listunspent/):

> `listunspent ( minconf maxconf ["address",...] include_unsafe query_options )`
>
> Returns array of unspent transaction outputs
>   with between minconf and maxconf (inclusive) confirmations.

so `listunspent 3` would work for you?

Comment: Yes that's what I do now, but I was wondering if there was a way to modify the `safe` parameter to totally avoid the risk of picking an UTXO that have less than x confirmations in a transaction.
You can also use the `lockunspent` command for the same purpose.

Comment: You'd need to recompile Core for that.